# Is the EV3 brick balanced?

Tags: ev3

Where is the center of gravity located on the ev3 brick? Is it at the center of volume, or is it off?

Please note, I do not yet own an EV3 so I can't measure it myself.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to measure; I mean, I distinctly remember learning the topic at school... long ago...

Comment: Will depend a lot on the weight of the batteries, Using Alkaline or Lithium batteries (non-rechargable), the rechargeable battery pack or other rechargeable batteries.